# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Selection items in a multi-select cannot contain compound tuple-valued elements in JPA CriteriaQuery example

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql, querydsl

I am developing **Spring + Spring Data JPA + JPQL Hibernate Criteria scenario** in my project. In this project I developed the following test case and when I'm executing it, I see the following error. I know its a small mistake but dont know what it is. Please guide.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Selection items in a multi-select cannot contain compound tuple-valued elements
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.CriteriaBuilderImpl.checkMultiselect(CriteriaBuilderImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.CriteriaBuilderImpl.tuple(CriteriaBuilderImpl.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.CriteriaQueryImpl.multiselect(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.CriteriaQueryImpl.multiselect(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:101)
    at com.scheduler.test.ProductTest.testCriteriaQuerysMultiselect(ProductTest.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

**ProductCriteriaJPQLTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:application-context.xml")
@Transactional
@Rollback
public class ProductCriteriaJPQLTest {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    private CriteriaBuilder cb;
    CriteriaQuery<Object> criteriaQuery;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        criteriaQuery = cb.createQuery();
    }
    // CriteriaQuery's multiselect
    @Test
    public void testCriteriaQuerysMultiselect(){
        CriteriaQuery<Tuple> q = cb.createTupleQuery();
        Root<Product> c = q.from(Product.class);
        q.multiselect(cb.tuple(c.get("productCode"), c.get("productVendor"), c.get("productline").get("productLine")));

        List<Tuple> results = em.createQuery(q).getResultList();
        for (Tuple t : results) {
            System.out.println("ProductCode: " + t.get(0) + ", ProductName: " + t.get(1)+", ProductVendor : "+t.get(2));
        }
    }
}
```

**Product.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="products")
@NamedQuery(name="Product.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM Product p")
public class Product implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
//  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String productCode;

    private double buyPrice;

    private double msrp;

    @Lob
    private String productDescription;

    private String productName;

    private String productScale;

    private String productVendor;

    private short quantityInStock;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Orderdetail
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="product")
    private List<Orderdetail> orderdetails;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Productline
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="productLine")
    private Productline productline;
     // Assume the setters and getters are present
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you need any other info.

EDIT-1 : As suggested, I tried below but still its not working

```
@Test
    public void testCriteriaQuerysMultiselect(){
        CriteriaQuery<Tuple> query = cb.createTupleQuery();

        Root<Product> product = query.from(Product.class);
        query.multiselect(cb.tuple(product.get("productCode")));

        List<Tuple> results = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
        for (Tuple t : results) {
            System.out.println("ProductCode: " + t.get(0) + ", ProductName: " + t.get(1)+", ProductVendor : "+t.get(2));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm really not familar with the `Tuple`, but did you try to remove this code: `c.get("productline").get("productLine")`? Only for test.

Comment: Dherik - Please see EDIT-1 above. Its not working though. I'm actually looking to do the multiselect not single select. I wonder no one yet answer to this post. # Need help of JPA experts

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach by the use of **Path**:

```
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> criteria = builder.createTupleQuery();
Root<Person> personRoot = criteria.from( Person.class );
Path<Long> idPath = personRoot.get( Person_.id );
Path<Integer> agePath = personRoot.get( Person_.age );
criteria.multiselect( idPath, agePath );
criteria.where( builder.equal( personRoot.get( Person_.eyeColor ), "brown" ) );
List<Tuple> tuples = em.createQuery( criteria ).getResultList();
for ( Tuple tuple : valueArray ) {
    assert tuple.get( 0 ) == tuple.get( idPath );
    assert tuple.get( 1 ) == tuple.get( agePath );
    ...
}
```

References: Example taken from [JBoss Hibernate Manual.  Chapter 9, Criteria Queries](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-typedquery-multiselect)